# Disable replacement of XML eXternal entities in Spring Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb2

I have an annotation based Spring web application controller which maps XML to an annotated plain old java object. Exemplary code as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Endpoint {

    @RequestMapping
    public void send(...) {
        ...
    } 
    ...
```

The mapping is automatically done via *Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter* and at the moment it is possible to reference and replace content in the received XML.

My question is, is it possible -- for example via beans.xml -- to configure the *Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter* such that the replacement of entities is prevented?

The converter is automatically created by Spring.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite a bean created by spring you just define your own bean of the same type. Additionally you can mark it @Primary. I haven't tried it with Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter, but it worked with ObjectMapper as described here :

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper